# how to add onClicklistener in your googlemap from AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, onclicklistener, google-maps-api-2

Good day,

Here is my code.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, OnMapReadyCallback {
private SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

supportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

}
```

My problem is, I don't have any idea on how to/where to add my onclicklistener for my map so that when I tap my map, it will add marker.

I am combining navigationdrawer and googlemap that is why I am using AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Once the map is ready in your onMapReady method, you can set listener as follows:

```
//add listener
googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            //add marker here using latLng as marker location
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                     .position(latLng)
                     .title("Hello world"));
        }
    });
```